# Why can't I initialize a value using braces with auto and pass it into this function

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, initializer-list

**Why can't I initialize a value with auto and pass it into a function that expects a decltype as a parameter?**

Let me set the scene, and show you a tiny program.

---

Here is a function that returns a value.

```
int Function(void);
```

In this case, it happens to be an integer, but the return type is subject to change.
That is why this next function, is written as followed:

```
void What_I_Take_Depends_On_Function(decltype(Function()) x);
```

If someone decides to change the return type of Function, then the deceleration of *this* function will not need to be changed.  Yes, the definition of the function may not handle the new type correctly, or if Function's return type is changed to void there will be an issue, but that is irrelevant to my problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int Function(void){return 5;}

void What_I_Take_Depends_On_Function(decltype(Function()) x){return;}

int main(){

    //assignments(Edit: these are initializations)
    int  var1 = Function();
    auto var2 = Function();

    //initializations
    int  var3 {Function()};
    auto var4 {Function()};

    What_I_Take_Depends_On_Function(var1); //works
    What_I_Take_Depends_On_Function(var2); //works
    What_I_Take_Depends_On_Function(var3); //works
    What_I_Take_Depends_On_Function(var4); //COMPILER ERROR

    //cannot convert ‘std::initializer_list<int>’ to ‘int’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void What_I_Take_Depends_On_Function(int)’

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

So why is var4 an initializer_list and not an int?
Can't auto just deduce that Function is going to return an int,
and then change the deceleration to that similar of var3?

Comment: Um, because `{...}` is an initializer list. `auto` tries to match what you give it, and you gave it an initializer list. Perhaps you meant `auto var4 (Function())`? (Parentheses, not braces.)

Comment: @RaymondChen I do not see how giving it an initializer list necessarily deduces to an initializer_list.

Comment: Because that's what the standard 7.1.6.4(2) says happens. "Obtain `P` from `T` by replacing the occurrences of `auto` with either a new invented type template parameter `U` or, **if the initializer is a `braced-init-list` (8.5.4), with `std::initializer_list<U>.`**"

Comment: By the way, your comment before `var1` and `var2` is wrong. They may look like assignments, but they are actually initializations (8.5(1)).

Comment: @RaymondChen but you make it sound like he should have known it before-hand. Matching an initializer list in no way necessarily means it has to be initializer_list. It could just as well have been `vector<int>`.

Comment: The whole point of `auto` is to match the type of the initializer. Curly braces are the syntax for generating a `std::initializer_list`. Therefore `auto` would naturally be expected to infer a `std::initializer_list`. I only looked it up to double check that the standard says the obvious thing. (Otherwise, what, "`auto` matches the type of the initializer, unless the initializer is a `std::initializer_list`, in which case it infers `std::vector`"? That would make it intentionally difficult to store a `std::initializer_list` in a variable.)

Comment: *"Curly braces are the syntax for generating a `std::initializer_list`"*, I am sorry that is totally wrong. Curly braces as in `{ 1, 2, 3 }` do not have anything intrinsically to do with `std::initializer_list`. They are just a way to initialize different things, among then `std::tuple<int, int, int>`, `std::vector<int>` and `std::initializer_list<int>`.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb That braces are used to represent multiple things does not contradict the statement that curly braces are the syntax for generating a `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: @raymond i do not understand what "the syntax for generating a" means.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb "The thing you type into your text editor in order to tell the compiler to create a `std::initializer_list`." There is only one way to create a nonempty `std::initializer_list`, and that is to use curly braces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The brace-init-list `{...}` is the new uniform initialization syntax for C++11, and it can be used to initialise any automatic, static or member variable *if the type of that variable is known*. These are a few examples of valid C++11 initialization:

```
class S
{
private:
  int _m;
public:
  S(int m) : _m { m }  // <== initialization of a member
  {}
};


int main() {

  constexpr unsigned i { 10 }; // <== initialization of a constexpr

  S s { i };  // <== initialization by calling constructor

  /* ... */
}
```

In **none of the above cases** will a `std::initializer_list` be generated. The brace-init-list `{...}` simply means the compiler will try to identify a **suitable constructor** for the given data type, whose argument list matches the contents of the brace-init-list (§8.5.4).

There are **two special cases:**

1. If **one of the constructors** defined for the given data type **takes a `std::initializer_list<T>` as argument**, and the contents of the brace-init-list are all implicitly convertible to `T`. This is the case when you use one of the built-in container types, e.g.

   ```
   std::vector<int> vec { 1, 2, 3 };
   ```

   `std::vector<T>` has a constructor `std::vector<T>(const std::initializer_list<T>)`, so the brace-init-list will be converted to a `std::initializer_list<int>` and as such copied  into the vector constructor. The constructor will iterate through the list and append the elements one by one.

   This is a bit of a trap when the list contains only one argument:

   ```
   std::vector<int> vec { 10 };
   ```

   Here, the same happens, so you will get a vector that contains the one element `10`. This is different from using old-style syntax:

   ```
   std::vector<int> vec(10);
   ```

   This calls the `std::vector<int>(const size_t)` constructor, i.e. it creates a vector of 10 default-initialised elements.
2. If the type of the variable to be initialised is not pre-determined, i.e. **when `auto` is used in the declaration:**

   ```
   auto v { 1, 2, 3 };
   ```

   In this case (§7.1.6.4/6) the compiler cannot identify a suitable constructor, because *any* data type that takes three integer (or convertible-to-integer) arguments is a possible candidate. The rule here is that the compiler assumes `std::initializer_list<int>` as the data type for `v`. That is what happens in your case as well.

In other words, using brace-init-lists is fine (and even encouraged) for initialization, but you can't readily combine it with `auto`. To solve you problem, you need to either declare the data type explicitly

```
int var4 { Function() };
```

or, to keep things flexible, use `decltype` here too:

```
decltype(Function()) var4 { Function() };
```

Alternatively, you can use old-style syntax:

```
auto v (Function());
```

Answer (score 2):

No, `auto` will not "just deduce that Function is going to return an int"; the way how the *auto* specifier works is well-defined in 7.1.6.4, and is as follows:

> (7.1.6.4/p6) Once the type of a *declarator-id* has been determined according to 8.3, the type of the declared variable
>   using the *declarator-id* is determined from the type of its initializer using the rules for template argument
>   deduction. Let `T` be the type that has been determined for a variable identifier `d`. Obtain `P` from `T` by
>   replacing the occurrences of `auto` with either a new invented type template parameter `U` or, if the initializer
>   is a `braced-init-list` (8.5.4), with `std::initializer_list<U>`. The type deduced for the variable `d` is then
>   the deduced `A` determined using the rules of template argument deduction from a function call (14.8.2.1),
>   where `P` is a function template parameter type and the initializer for `d` is the corresponding argument. If
>   the deduction fails, the declaration is ill-formed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a misunderstanding of syntax.
I was accustomed to initializing variables like this:

```
int i{0};
```

However, I need to initalize this type with parenthesis not brackets.
Thank you Raymond

Comment: What you say is wrong. Of course you can use `int i{0};` to declare an integer variable `i` and initialize it with `0`.

Answer (score 0):

@jogojapan gave a very good answer but things have changed since C++11 and I'd like to add some clarifications.

When using `auto` with braced initialization in C++11 everything was deduced to a `std::initializer_list<T>` but, this has changed in C++17 and even in C++14 with other compilers like MSVC.

For instance, if we had the following cases in C++11:

```
auto a = {42};    // std::initializer_list<int>
auto b {42};      // std::initializer_list<int>
auto c = {1, 2};  // std::initializer_list<int>
auto d {1, 2};    // std::initializer_list<int>
```

In C++17 (or earlier on MSVC) the deduced type depends on whether we use direct initialization or copy initialization.

- For copy initialization the deduced type will be a `std::initializer_list<T>` if all elements in the list have the same type, otherwise we'll get an error.
- For direct initialization the deduced type will be `T` if the list has only one element, otherwise we'll get a error.

Using the same examples as above with C++17:

```
auto a = {42};   // std::initializer_list<int>
auto b {42};     // int
auto c = {1, 2}; // std::initializer_list<int>
auto d {1, 2};   // error, too many elements in the list
```

`auto` behaves very differently based on how we initialize it and although is a very powerful tool, it is not recommend it to use it with braced initialization because in many cases it may not deduce the type we think will do and, this can lead to all sorts of problems.