# Extract template type from initializer list

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a problem with C++11 templated code. I have a template function

```
    template <typename T> 
    f(const std::vector<T>& v)
    {
      /* do something here*/
    };
```

When I invoke `f(v)`, where `v` is declared as `std::vector<some_type> v;`, the program compiles just fine. However, if I pass an initializer list to `f`, say `f({a,b,c})`, where `a`, `b`, `c` are all of the same type, say `some_type`, I get a compile error: `couldn't infer template argument 'T'`, so I have to manually specify the type when invoking `f`. That is, for example, `f<int>({a,b,c});` compiles just fine when `a`, `b` and `c` are all `int`s. Is there any way of inferring the template type `T` from a standard initializer list given that the function is defined as taking a parameter of `std::vector<T>`? Basically I just want to be able to invoke `f({initializer_list});` without specifying the type of the elements of the `initializer_list` in angle brackets when invoking `f`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just define

```
template<typename T>
void f(const std::initializer_list<T>& v) {
  f(std::vector<T>(v));
}
```

For this to work, the initializer_list has to be of some unambiguous type, so `f({0, 1.41421, 2.71828, 3.14159 })` won't work, but `f({0.0, 1.41421, 2.71828, 3.14159})` will.

Comment: no, still get the same error `note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure`

Comment: It actually works, thanks much, I was invoking `f<std::vector<T>>(l)` instead of `f(std::vector<T>(l))`, so I was not actually constructing a vector out of the initializer list... C++ template syntax sucks big time...

Comment: One more question :) Now, suppose I have an initializer list containing let's say `{x,y,z}`, where `x`, `y`, `z` are 3 different types but all safely cast-able to another `W` type (say `x` is `double`, `y` is `int` and `z` is `float`, and all of them are cast-able to a `W`, in this example a `double`). How can I write down a generic function that accepts this list as a parameter without complaining that the types do not match?

Comment: All this headache comes from the fact that I'm using `Eigen` matrix library, in which `A` is of type `Matrix`, however `A*B` is of type `MatrixProduct`, `A+B*C` is of type `Sum_of_Product` and so on... but all of these expressions are safely cast-able to `Matrix`

Comment: @vsoftco: AFAIK, you'd have to explicitly cast them each expression to `Matrix` (I'd use a macro, personally). initialization_lists have their limits. Of course, if you were just using `Eigen` matrices, you wouldn't actually need to template `f`, and without templates, you could achieve automatic conversions. It's pretty well one or the other, in a nutshell.

Comment: Yes, but if I don't template them then my code won't work for `Matrix<double>`, `Matrix<int>`, and a product of 2 matrices specified as a parameter (which is now a different type), without an explicit cast... so I guess there is no way around it, if I have different types in the initializer list I'll just specify the template argument for the invoking function, like `f<Matrix<double> > ({my initializer list of Eigen expressions})`; `f` will then cast everything in the initializer list to `Matrix<double>` (of course, if the cast is valid).

Comment: @vsoftco: sad but probably true. Presumably you could template on the Matrix parameter, and reduce that to `f<double>` or `f<int>`

Comment: Yeah I did that, still it pisses me off that I cannot totally get rid of the braces when invoking something like `f( {A, A*B} );` Here `A` and `A*B` have different types, even though they are just matrices over the same scalar field, but `Eigen` is defining them as `Matrix` (for `A`) and `MatrixProduct` (for `A*B`). But I guess I have to live with this...

Comment: @vsoftco: I presume it is doing that in order to lazily evaluate the matrix arithmetic. If the matrix expression types have some way to extract their base numeric type, you could probably pull off some template magic. It sounds vaguely interesting, but it's getting to late for me :( If I think of something tomorrow, I'll add another answer.

Comment: Yes, you're right, Eigen does lazy evaluation, so it doesn't really evaluate A*B unless you asked it to. However, in my code, all expression have to be evaluated. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In an [answer to another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12232658/434551), [jogojapan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/777186/jogojapan) said,

> The brace-init-list {...} is the new uniform initialization syntax for C++11, and it can be used to initialise any automatic, static or member variable *if the type of that variable is known*.

Since the type of the argument being passed is known when you call:

```
f<int>({a,b,c});
```

it works.

When you use:

```
f({a,b,c});
```

the type has to be deduced. Hence, it does not work.

If you want to take advantage of type of `a`, you can use:

```
f<decltype(a)>({a,b,c});
```

That should work.

Comment: OP is talking about a function. You seem to be talking about a constructor (i.e. object initialization), which is completely different.

Comment: @rici In this particular usage, construction of a temporary object from an `initializer_list` is necessary.

Comment: don't get it... so basically you're saying that you cannot deduce template types from an initializer list? The type should be known at compile time, it's a template after all...

Comment: @vsoftco yes, that's what I understand.

Comment: well that is strange as the type IS KNOWN at the compile time, the type checking should be done at compile time and not run-time. The parameters I am applying the function to are declared before and have a very well defined type :)

Comment: You can't deduce template parameters in a declaration. You can deduce them in a function call, but template parameter deduction in function calls does not take into account conversions, so the initializer_list to vector conversion precludes deduction.